# is this possible to create a pagination like << A B C D E F and so on… >> instead of << 1 2 3 4 and so on… >> in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

> is this possible to create a pagination  like << A B C D E F and so
>   on… >> instead of << 1 2 3 4 and so on… >> in joomla 2.5
>
> or any extensions available  here am searched in web but i didn't get
>   any solution
>
> can u please give solution

Comment: its not logical how you represent more than 26 pages ??

Comment: i mean only for 10 to 15 character enough

Comment: Its not logical so you can't find any extension related to this. only option is you have to customize the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks odd. However you can do it easily if you know Joomla pagination which is very simple.
I don't think there is any in-built extension. Read this doc http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_JPagination_in_your_component for more information.